# Хотелось бы реализовать чтобы файл не скачивался, а просто открывался в новой вкладке

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, ftp

У меня есть загрузка файла с FTP-сервера. Хотелось бы реализовать чтобы файл не скачивался, а просто открывался в новой вкладке.

```
public static void ReadFileFromFTP(string ftp_file_path, out byte[] s)
        {
            s = null;
            try
            {
                string ftpfullpath = ftp_file_path;

                System.Net.WebClient request = new System.Net.WebClient();
                request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_ftp_username, _ftp_password);

                s = request.DownloadData(ftpfullpath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: что такое `просто открывался`? Кем, где? Как вы можете отрыть содержимое файла, не скачивая его?

Comment: Показанный код выполняется где? В контроллере вашего asp.net приложения? Или на клиентской машине?

Comment: JavaScript `window.open(url, '_blank').focus();` выполните на клиенте и готово. Или пусть пользователь нажмет на ссылку `<a href="url" target="_blank">Ссылка</a>`.

Comment: @tym32167 Открывался сам файл в новой вкладке, не скачивая его. В моём проекту сейчас можно просмотреть файл, после того как скачиваешь его.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov 
Данный метод используете в контроллере.

Comment: @aepot  По вью думаю всё нормально работает. `<td scope="row"><a href="@Url.Action("method", "controller", new { @id_app = dRow["id_app"], @id = dRow["id"] })" target="_blank">@dRow["Name"]</a></td> `

Comment: Ну раз всё нормально работает, то вопрос решён